# Android - Can I use LibGdx for game screen only?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, libgdx, game-engine

I have developed a game in android but now I want to make the gameplay or game screen in LibGdx as I am familiar with it. So, can I make game screen in LibGdx and use splash, login, setting screen etc. which are made in android ?
If Yes, Then how can I do so?

Comment: Why don't you do login and settings screen in LibGDX too? If it's a game, why don't you do all of it with LibGDX?

Comment: @Faith..because I have already done that in android. I have also made leaderboard and I don't want to make all of it again.

Comment: LibGDX is also in Java. When you write a screen in core class it also works in Android too. You should only write Android specific code in Android folder. I have 5 games with leaderboards, splash screens, and settings screen in Java and also in LibGDX. Your settings screen should extend screen and leaderboards. For leaderboard code, you implement interface on core and desktop folders that does nothing but in Android folder you use the Leaderboard.

Comment: A game is a whole structure. You write all screens in java in core folder then if you have something only should available in Android, like bluetooth class of Android or Play Services, etc., you write that part in Android folder. To invoke that method you use interface on both folders. For this behaviour check Admob and Play Services code(BaseGameUtils lib) for LibGDX. You will get the idea.

Comment: @Faith..thanks. I know that we should write our logic in core folder for cross platform support. As game logic is getting more complex so I thought it would be better to make game screen in LibGdx making all of it in LibGdx is not an option for me.

Comment: You can use LibGDX for how much you wish. You can even use LibGDX for matrix or vector calculation too without using it's visual elements.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer your question again. You don't have to use core or desktop folders. You can code everything for Android folder with Ads, Play Services, etc. if you wish.

Let me describe how you do it.

1. Create a class that extends `AndroidApplication` this is your MainActivity class where everything starts.You add a game view and ad view to this class game view class extends `Game` class on create() method of AndroidApplication class.

   ```
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   AndroidApplicationConfiguration config = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
   // create view that contains game
   View viewGame = initializeForView(new MyGame(this), config);
   // create ads
   setUpAds();
   layoutMain = new RelativeLayout(this);
   // add game view
   layoutMain.addView(viewGame, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
   setContentView(layoutMain);
   ```

   }
2. You set a class that extends `ScreenAdapter` insde `create()` method
   of your `MyGame` class. and send instance of MyGame class to screen
   classes as parameter to change screen using Game instance and
   everything inside classes like Splash, Game, Setting or anything
   else is coded in Java(Android) and you can easily change screens
   using `game.setScreen((new MainMenuScreen(game)));` That's all the
   logic.

Comment: I get the feeling that if I understood about 1.5x as much as I do right now, this answer would solve a problem I'm having. ;-(